# How to stop certain rows from printing if one single cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to print the active sheet. There is always data on page 1,2,3,6 so I have selected "" for the cell and have a cell selected that will never have data in it so they will always print. For pages 4 & 5 I only want them to print if there is something in one specific cell defined and if the cell is empty it will not print that page(s). Page 4 only has one cell I need to check if it is blank but on page 5 I need to check 4 cells and if any of them are not blank I need page 5 to print. The first 3 pages print fine right now but then I get an error when I get to page 4

I've tried changing the if statement for page 4 so that it will look at the single cell and then if it meets the rule it will hide the cells (I would like them to then unhide after printing is done of page 6 or just not print those rows instead of hiding and then unhiding).

```
Public Sub PrintReport()
```

Dim strSheetName As String
strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

If Range("A2").Value = "" Then 'Page 1

Range("A1:R91").PrintOut

If Range("A93").Value = "" Then 'Page 2

Range("A92:R157").PrintOut

If Range("A158").Value = "" Then 'Page 3

Range("A158:R199").PrintOut

If Range("C202").Value = "" Then 'Page 4

Range("A200:A243").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Else

Range("A200:A243").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Range("C246").Value And Range("A269").Value And Range("E285").Value And Range("E293").Value = "" Then 'Page 5

Range("A244:A301").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Else

Range("A244:A301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Range("P302").Value = "" Then ' Page 6

Range("A320:R325").PrintOut

End If

End If

End If

End If

End If

End If

End Sub

I would like it to print out each page that meets the specified criteria and then prints or does not print those specified cells. Pages 1-3 print fine as they will always print, but it always errors out on page 4 where the range is noted as Range("A200:A243").Hidden = True. I need this to either hide and then unhide those rows after printing the remaining pages or just not print it and not unhide.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to adopt more standard indentation methods. This will go a long way in helping you to trouble shoot your code

Comment: Excel VBA help is your friend: "The specified range must span an entire column or row." You can use `Range("A200:A243").entirerow.Hidden =(Range("C202").Value = "")` and avoid the If statement.

Comment: This code doesn't compile - you've got an extra `End If` in there.

Comment: @SJR - But what if I do want to print that page will this still print? Also how could I get it to unhide those rows after page 6 is printed so when I look at the document they are still visible?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I’m very aware but have sadly never used the tool. I only have windows access at work and can’t install the tool. Idiot with a mac for personal computer here.... (*for now at least*)

Comment: @urdearboy that comment was for the OP though - I only meant to echo your comment about adopting "more standard indentation methods" :)

Comment: Yes I suppose that formulation wouldn't work so use the answer provided. And please attend to the other comments.

Comment: I will work on my standardized indention method. I copied part of code from someplace else and did not reformat because I didn't want to waste my time if I couldn't get the code to work for me. The additional End If was because I had one more line of code I was trying but it was not even close to working so I deleted that line before posting in here but didn't remove the End If.

Answer (score 2):

You can only hide rows or columns, not just any range. Add `.EntireRow` to all your hide/unhide statements to have the hide/unhide work on the entire row, like so:

```
Range("A244:A301").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: I updated the code above with what you suggested above. It didn't have any errors and printed the first three pages, but did not print page 6 which should have printed. I also put data in the field so it should have printed page 5 but it did not print.

Comment: @CMig As it is, the code you've posted won't compile, and half of it is commented out. I'd suggest starting by what others have mentioned, and properly indenting. It's not a waste of time; it's a way to see at a glance where logical blocks of code begin and end. I suspect your issue is not having your if conditions set up the way you want, but not knowing what the way you want it is, we can't really help any further.

Comment: The only things commented out are the page numbers. When I re-posted the code in there it took out some of the returns for some reason. I noticed the End If's that it removed but not the others. It is a waste of time to fix all the indenting if I just delete all the code because it doesn't work, not because it wasn't formatted nicely, but because the code will never work. I've figured out a better way to just hide the rows, print, and then unhide the rows but it keeps printing the places the page breaks are that are now blank even though the rows are hidden.